# Creating a Specs2 matcher in a modular way

Tags: scala, specs, specs2

I have functions `A => Double`. I want to check whether two such functions give the same results (up to a tolerance, using the existing `beCloseTo` matcher) for a given set of values.

I want to be able to write:

```
type TF = A => Double
(f: TF) must computeSameResultsAs(g: TF,tolerance: Double, tests: Set[A])
```

I want to build this matcher in a modular way, not simply writing a `Matcher[TF]` from scratch.

It might be even nicer if I could write:

```
(f: TF) must computeSameResultsAs(g: TF)
               .withTolerance(tolerance)
               .onValues(tests: Set[A])
```

Also I want to get a reasonable description when the matcher fails.

### Edit

After sleeping over it I came up with the following.

```
def computeSameResultsAs[A](ref: A => Double, tolerance: Double, args: Set[A]): Matcher[A => Double] = 
  args.map(beCloseOnArg(ref, tolerance, _)).reduce(_ and _)

def beCloseOnArg[A](ref: A => Double, tolerance: Double, arg: A): Matcher[A => Double] = 
  closeTo(ref(arg), tolerance) ^^ ((_: A => Double).apply(arg))
```

This is much shorter than Eric's solution but doesn't provide a good failure message. What I'd love to be able is rename the mapped value in the second method. Something like the following (which does not compile).

```
def beCloseOnArg[A](ref: A => Double, tolerance: Double, arg: A): Matcher[A => Double] = 
  closeTo(ref(arg), tolerance) ^^ ((_: A => Double).apply(arg) aka "result on argument " + arg)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want to write things with the second version you need to create a new `Matcher` class encapsulating the functionality of the `beCloseTo` matcher:

```
def computeSameResultsAs[A](g: A => Double, 
                            tolerance: Double = 0.0, 
                            values: Seq[A] = Seq()) = TFMatcher(g, tolerance, values)

case class TFMatcher[A](g: A => Double, 
                        tolerance: Double = 0.0, 
                        values: Seq[A] = Seq()) extends Matcher[A => Double] {

  def apply[S <: A => Double](f: Expectable[S]) = {
    // see definition below
  }

  def withTolerance(t: Double) = TFMatcher(g, t, values)
  def onValues(tests: A*) = TFMatcher(g, tolerance, tests)
}
```

This class allows to use the syntax you're after:

```
val f = (i: Int) => i.toDouble
val g = (i: Int) => i.toDouble + 0.1

"f must be close to another similar function with a tolerance" in {
  f must computeSameResultsAs[Int](g).withTolerance(0.5).onValues(1, 2, 3)          
}
```

Now, let's see how to reuse the `beCloseTo` matcher in the `apply` method:

```
def apply[S <: A => Double](f: Expectable[S]) = {
  val res = ((v: A) => beCloseTo(g(v) +/- tolerance).apply(theValue(f.value(v)))).forall(values)

  val message = "f is "+(if (res.isSuccess) "" else "not ")+
                "close to g with a tolerance of "+tolerance+" "+
                "on values "+values.mkString(",")+": "+res.message
   result(res.isSuccess, message, message, f)
 }
```

In the code above, we apply a function returning a `MatcherResult` [to a sequence of values](http://etorreborre.github.com/specs2/guide/org.specs2.guide.Matchers.html#Matching+with+a+sequence+of+values):

```
((v: A) => beCloseTo(g(v) +/- tolerance).apply(theValue(f.value(v)))).forall(values)
```

Note that:

1. `f` is an `Expectable[A => Double]` so we need to take its actual `value` to be able to use it
2. similarly we can only apply an `Expectable[T]` to a `Matcher[T]` so we need to use the method `theValue` to transform `f.value(v)` to an `Expectable[Double]` (from the `MustExpectations` trait)

Finally, we when have the result of the `forall` matching, we can customize the result messages by using:

1. the inherited `result` method building a `MatchResult` (what the `apply` method of any `Matcher` should return
2. passing it a boolean saying if the execution of `beCloseTo` was successful: `.isSuccess`
3. passing it nicely formatted "ok" and "ko" messages, based on the input and on the result message of the `beCloseTo` matching
4. passing it the `Expectable` which was used to do the matching in the first place: `f`, so that the final result has a type of `MatchResult[A => Double]`

I'm not sure how more modular we can get given your requirements. It looks to me that the best we can do here is to reuse `beCloseTo` with `forall`.

**UPDATE**

A shorter answer might be something like this:

```
val f = (i: Int) => i.toDouble
val g = (i: Int) => i.toDouble + 1.0

"f must be close to another similar function with a tolerance" in {
  f must computeSameResultsAs[Int](g, tolerance = 0.5, values = Seq(1, 2, 3))          
}

def computeSameResultsAs[A](ref: A => Double, tolerance: Double, values: Seq[A]): Matcher[A => Double] = (f: A => Double) => {
  verifyFunction((a: A) => (beCloseTo(ref(a) +/- tolerance)).apply(theValue(f(a)))).forall(values)
}
```

The code above creates a failure message like:

```
In the sequence '1, 2, 3', the 1st element is failing: 1.0 is not close to 2.0 +/- 0.5
```

This should almost work out-of-the-box. The missing part is an implicit conversion from `A => MatchResult[_]` to `Matcher[A]` (which I'm going to add to the next version):

```
implicit def functionResultToMatcher[T](f: T => MatchResult[_]): Matcher[T] = (t: T) => {
  val result = f(t)
  (result.isSuccess, result.message)
}
```

You can use [`foreach`](http://etorreborre.github.com/specs2/guide/org.specs2.guide.Matchers.html#Matching+with+a+sequence+of+values) instead of `forall` if you want to get all the failures:

```
1.0 is not close to 2.0 +/- 0.5; 2.0 is not close to 3.0 +/- 0.5; 3.0 is not close to 4.0 +/- 0.5
```

**UPDATE 2**

This gets better everyday. With the latest specs2 snapshot you can write:

```
def computeSameResultsAs[A](ref: A => Double, tolerance: Double, values: Seq[A]): Matcher[A => Double] = (f: A => Double) => {
  ((a: A) => beCloseTo(ref(a) +/- tolerance) ^^ f).forall(values)
}
```

**UPDATE 3**

And now with the latest specs2 snapshot you can write:

```
def computeSameResultsAs[A](ref: A => Double, tolerance: Double, values: Seq[A]): Matcher[A => Double] = (f: A => Double) => {
  ((a: A) => beCloseTo(ref(a) +/- tolerance) ^^ ((a1: A) => f(a) aka "the value")).forall(values)
}
```

The failure message will be:

```
In the sequence '1, 2, 3', the 1st element is failing: the value '1.0' is not close to 2.0 +/- 0.5
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Eric. Your suggestion works but basically writes a new matcher. I have added to my question a shorter way of creating the matcher (more like what I thought of), but it lacks proper messages.

Comment: Any chance to add the feature to "decorate" a `^^` transformation with something like an aka? After all when having a `^^ (A => B)`, you need to explain how you obtained the `B` from the `A`, like "the first element of` if doing `^^ (_.head)` for some collection.